# What conditions a function$ f: X \to Y $Must satisfy so that the inverse image of compact is also compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

If f is closed such that the inverse image of a unitary set is compact, I think it's worth it. But are there other conditions?

Comment: When you wrote “unitary”, my guess is that you meant “singular”.

Comment: I think if $f$ is open the claim is true... On another hand, constant functions provide many examples of closed mapping for which this type of claim fails.

Answer (score 3):

Such a function is called a proper map. The Wikipedia article with title 'proper map' mentions 'several competing descriptions' so should be a good source of leads.